# Sorcerer, mage, wizard, magician, what's the difference?

Tags: wizard, sorcerer

Sorcerer, mage, wizard, magician, what's the difference? I'm a non-native english speaker.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language rather than RPGs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the question? Are you seeking lingual or functional differences? Are you after the origins of the words or simply what the difference between them are in the context of a particular game? If so, which game?

Comment: You may be interested in [English Language & Usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language Learners SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Either would accept this question, I believe.

Comment: [ell.se] will be your best bet for this question.

Comment: I actually like the question, but yes it needs rephrasing. It would be interesting to have some examples of how Wizards, Sorcerers etc, differ or are similar but just named differently.

Comment: @Knartz, without a system specified it would be too broad.